# Application of MAP criteria

Tags: digital-communications, noise, probability

This question has been asked in GATE 2019. I am unable to understand how MAP criteria is "applied" here. I've read about MAP but I'm unable to get how they're solving it by graphical method.

Please explain what they are doing here, and also what do they mean by "optimum threshold exists here" ?
[image]

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The MAP criterion minimizes the average probability of error, which in your case reads
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P_e &= P \left( -1 \right) P \left( Y>\theta \mid -1 \right) + 
P \left( +1 \right) P \left( Y<\theta \mid +1 \right) \\
&= 0.2 \int_{\theta}^{+1} f_Y \left( y \mid -1 \right) \mathit{dy} + 
0.8 \int_{-1}^{\theta} f_Y \left( y \mid +1 \right) \mathit{dy} \,.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Therefore, the optimum threshold, call it $\hat{\theta}$, is *optimum* in terms of minimizing $P_e$.
Exploiting the previous equation and the definitions of the random variables $X$ and $N$, you get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P_e &= 0.2 \times 0.25 \times \left(1-\theta\right) + 
0.8 \times 0.25 \times \left(1+\theta\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{20} \times \left(1-\theta\right) + 
\frac{4}{20} \times\left(1+\theta\right) .
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Minimizing $P_e$ w.r.t. $\theta$, you obtain $\hat{\theta} = -1$.

An easier way to solve your problem would be: look at the plot, and select $\hat{\theta}$ such that it minimizes the sum between the *right tail* of the left function (i.e., the grey area) and the *left tail* of the right function. In this way you easily get the solution, but the analytical way is, in my opinion, preferable to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

MAP is an acronym for "**m**aximum ***a** **p**osteriori"* or "**m**aximum ***a** posteriori* **p**robability" and the MAP *decision rule* says

> Choose whichever hypothesis has the maximum *a posteriori* probability given the observation.

The *a priori* probabilities of the two hypotheses $X=+1$ and $X=-1$ are given to be $0.8$ and $0.2$ respectively, while the *conditional* densities of the observation $Y$ are $f_{Y\mid X = +1}(y\mid X=+1)$ and  $f_{Y\mid X = -1}(y\mid X=-1)$.  The *unconditional* density of $Y$ is thus
$$f_Y(y) = 0.8 f_{Y\mid X = +1}(y\mid X=+1) + 0.2f_{Y\mid X = -1}(y\mid X=-1)\tag{*}.$$

Given that we have observed that the random variable $Y$ has taken on value $y$, the *a posteriori* probabilities of the discrete random variable $X$ are
\begin{align}
P(X = +1\mid Y = y) &= \dfrac{0.8f_{Y\mid X = +1}(y\mid X=+1)}{0.8 f_{Y\mid X = +1}(y\mid X=+1) + 0.2f_{Y\mid X = -1}(y\mid X=-1)}\tag{1}\\
P(X = -1\mid Y = y) &= \dfrac{0.2f_{Y\mid X = -1}(y\mid X=-1)}{0.8 f_{Y\mid X = +1}(y\mid X=+1) + 0.2f_{Y\mid X = -1}(y\mid X=-1)}\tag{2}
\end{align}
where we note that the denominators of the fractions in $(1)$ and $(2)$ are just the right side of $(*)$.  Thus, in deciding which of $P(X = +1\mid Y = y)$ and $P(X = -1\mid Y = y)$ is the larger probability, we can ignore the denominators in $(1)$ and $(2)$ and just compare $0.8f_{Y\mid X = +1}(y\mid X=+1)$ with $0.2f_{Y\mid X = -1}(y\mid X=-1$. We will arrive at the same decision as our more painstaking colleagues who laboriously compute $(*)$, and then the right sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$, and only then check which of which of $P(X = +1\mid Y = y)$ and $P(X = -1\mid Y = y)$ is the larger! The easier path is the one chosen by the examiner who set the problem in GATE 2019. In that problem,
\begin{align}
f_{Y\mid X = +1} &\sim \mathcal U[-1,3]\\
f_{Y\mid X = -1} &\sim \mathcal U[-3,1]
\end{align}
and thus $0.8f_{Y\mid X = +1}(y\mid X=+1)$ has value $0.8\times 0.25 = 0.2 = \frac{4}{20}$ for $-1 \leq y \leq 3$ while $0.2f_{Y\mid X = -1}(y\mid X=-1)$ has value $0.2\times 0.25 = 0.05 = \frac{1}{20}$ for $-3 \leq y \leq -1$.  These two functions are shown on the graph in the solution provided, and hopefully it is a no-brainer to come to the conclusion that if $Y$ has value $> -1$, the MAP decision is $\hat{X}=+1$ while of $Y$ has value $<-1$, the MAP decision is $\hat{X}=-1$.  Look, Ma! No need to take derivatives etc to determine the optimum threshold etc. I have no clue as to what "optimum threshold *exists* here" means; the optimum threshold *is* $-1$ and, in my opinion, the label on the arrow in the figure should have read just "optimum threshold" and not what it says.

In this simple example, the decision is always correct if $X$ has taken on value $+1$. If $X$ has taken on value $-1$, the decision will be incorrect if $Y$ happens to be $> -1$, that is, half the time, but since $X$ takes on value $-1$ with probability $0.2$, the probability of error of this MAP decision rule is $0.2 \times 0.5 = 0.1$. Very conveniently, this is just the shaded area in the figure in the solution. More generally, the probability of error would be the sum of the areas of two disjoint regions on this type of figure, but here, as explained above, one of these two regions is empty.

Comment: Thanks Dilip. Two more queries, if we reverse the a priori probabilities of +1 and -1, then will optimum threshold be "+1" , and minimum probability of error 0.10 (same as before ) ? GATE has asked same type of question in 2015, 2018 and 2019, everytime they gave the a priori probability of the higher value more, is there a specific reason behind this ?

Comment: @SYEDMAJIDAHMAD. Work out the details for yourself.  Also, consider the case when $X$ is _equally likely_ to have values $\pm 1$. Is the threshold unique in this case?